# How to complete reminders with no due date (or due today) in 1 line without creating a dummy reminder?

Tags: types, applescript, typeerror, reminders

I am trying to write an AppleScript that completes all reminders that match a name and list, but if they're either without a due date OR overdue (due date < today).

I know that I can loop over reminders to solve this, BUT looping over reminders is intractably slow when there are *lots* of reminders, so I would like to know how to do this in 1 line, which is multiple orders of magnitude faster in my use case.

When I run this script:

```
set curDate to current date
tell application "Reminders"
    set myList to "Reminders"
    set myTitle to "Test 1"
    set completed of every reminder in list myList whose completed is false and name is myTitle and (due date is missing value or due date is less than curDate) to true
end tell
```

I get this error:

```
error "Reminders got an error: Can’t make missing value into type date." number -1700 from missing value to date
```

that highlights this line:

```
set completed of every reminder in list myList whose completed is false and name is myTitle and (due date is missing value or due date is less than curDate) to true
```

I cannot seem to get the `type` of `due date` and the type of `missing value` to match **without** creating a dummy reminder... observe: the following code *works*:

```
set curDate to current date
tell application "Reminders"
    set myList to "Reminders"
    set myTitle to "Test 1"
    -- Create a dummy reminder whose due date is "missing value"
    set newremin to make new reminder
    set name of newremin to "Debugging delete me"
    set completed of every reminder in list myList whose completed is false and name is myTitle and (due date is (due date of newremin) or due date is less than curDate) to true
end tell
```

I created 2 reminders to test this, both named "Test 1".  One is due today and the other has no due date.  The working example with the dummy reminder succeeds in completing both reminders, and runs relatively fast.

Is there a way to modify the 1 `set completed...` line to work without having to create a dummy reminder?

Comment: Incidentally, I have tried `due date is missing value` and every variant I can think of to compare `missing value` with `due date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated Answer

There was a problem with my first answer which I worked out.  Neither my script nor the script in the other answer would complete a due reminder shown in the Reminders app as not completed.  I think that this is due to either a reminder synch issue (between multiple devices) or due to the fact that I completed then "un-completed" the reminder, either of which causes duplicate reminders.

Regardless of the cause, in this situation, the `every reminder...` statement only compares the search criteria to one (and it's not the one the Reminders app was displaying).  Here's a screen recording showing that the AppleScript never loops on the currently due reminder shown in the reminders app:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S0ToJcMK7o5wOspwOG_eIVIJ1xowA6fg&authuser=hepcat72%40gmail.com&usp=drive_fs

Oddly, the "future-due" reminders in that recurrence do get evaluated & returned.  I discovered that if I return *every* reminder and search through the results, I find a recurring reminder whose due date matches the incomplete reminder shown in the Reminders app, but the properties of the returned reminder shows it to be complete.

Also, the script, given `whose due date is greater than curDate` only returns future-due recurring reminders if a reminder in the recurrence has been completed then "un-completed".

Another interesting/odd behavior is that if I do not include `whose due date is...`, one of the incomplete reminders returned shows as due nearly a year from now and I can find no such reminder in the actual sqlite3 database.

Regardless, the only solution I have found that is both fast and robust to these reminder database inconsistencies is to obtain the reminder ID's from the sqlite3 database and loop in the AppleScript on those reminder IDs.

I have a perl script I wrote to find reminders in the sqlite3 database, though I have not published it publicly yet.  However, if you write your own script, here is a screen recording proof of concept of what to have it return and how you can use that reminder ID to complete the reminder:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S2WEyhUiL9CsyWcfFCvJ0CV7OqLqtAO2&authuser=hepcat72%40gmail.com&usp=drive_fs

I will eventually publish my perl script and I will try to update this answer when I do, but I will say that my resulting AppleScript/PerlScript combo always (so far) seems to complete every intended reminder thrown at it, though I will add a caveat that if another device's sqlite3 database has a different set of IDs in it's sqlite3 database, this script cannot complete those unless it is run on that device.

In the meantime, here is the content of my AppleScript (edited for brevity), which shows the calls to my perl script:

```
set status to my completeReminder("Feed the cat", "Reminders")

on completeReminder(myTitle, myList)
    
    set curDate to current date
    
    set fcmd to "perl getReminder.pl -c incomplete -t '" & myTitle & "' -l '" & myList & "' -d future-due --ids"
    set ccmd to "perl getReminder.pl -c incomplete -t '" & myTitle & "' -l '" & myList & "' -d past-or-no-due --ids"
    
    try
        set future_due to paragraphs of (do shell script fcmd)
        set to_complete to paragraphs of (do shell script ccmd)
    on error errmsg
        return {-1, errmsg}
    end try
    
    if (count of to_complete) is equal to 0 then
        return {0, "No matching reminders"}
    end if
    
    if (count of future_due) is greater than 0 then
        -- Version to avoid completing future-due reminders
        try
            with timeout of 600 seconds
                tell application "Reminders"
                    repeat with remid in to_complete
                        set rems to (every reminder whose id is remid)
                        repeat with rem in rems
                            set rem to item 1 of rems
                            set completed of rem to true
                        end repeat
                    end repeat
                end tell
            end timeout
        on error errmsg
            return {-1, errmsg}
        end try
    else
        -- This may or may not actually be faster than the loop using the IDs above - I did not make that comparison, but it was much faster in my previous versions
        tell application "Reminders"
            set completed of every reminder in list myList whose completed is false and name is myTitle to true
        end tell
    end if
    return {(count of to_complete), (count of to_complete) & " reminder(s) completed"}
end completeReminder
```

## Old Answer

While I have not figured out a way to do this in 1 line, I did note that speed was the reason I was looking to do this in 1 line, and combined with the other answer, I have found my way to a solution that runs in 2 times the fastest speed possible that you get from using a 1-line `every reminder` statement without the need to create a dummy reminder.

Even with my dummy reminder 1-line solution, I tested to discover that it was the dummy reminder creation that was taking over a minute to complete.  The 1-line statement was going very fast once it had the dummy reminder to compare a "missing value due date" to any due dates of the reminders.

I also tried searching for an existing dummy reminder, but still, it ran in over a minute's time.  I suspected it was the requirement of a return from the `every reminder` statement that is the time-limiting bottleneck. However, with more testing, I found that I can get a quick (roughly 7-second) execution of a `first reminder` statement that does a return.

I also realized that all I'm trying to do is avoid completing reminders **due in the future**, so I was able to combine that with a `first reminder` statement to determine if there actually existed matching reminders that I do not want to complete based on the due date.  The result is the following script that completes the 2 reminders (no due date and a past-due due date) in roughly 13 seconds (when there are no reminders that explicitly should not be completed).  Worst case, if there are reminders to avoid completing, it runs in the time of @Robert Kniazidis's solution (between 1m30s and 2m30s) plus 7 seconds:

```
set curDate to current date
set myList to "Reminders"
set myTitle to "Test 1"
tell application "Reminders"
    try
        -- If no reminders with due dates to avoid exist, this errors out with an index error on the first line and we can complete every matching reminder regardless of due date in the catch. Otherwise, we continue on with a slow solution...
        first reminder in list myList whose completed is false and name is myTitle and due date is greater than curDate
        
        -- If there are reminders to avoid completing, do the slow roll...
        try
            with timeout of 600 seconds
                set theReminders to reminders of list myList whose completed is false and name is myTitle
                repeat with theReminder in theReminders
                    try
                        set dueDate to (due date of theReminder) as date
                        if dueDate is less than curDate then set completed of theReminder to true
                    on error
                        set completed of theReminder to true
                    end try
                end repeat
            end timeout
        on error errmsg
            return errmsg
        end try
    on error
        -- Complete every matching reminder regardless of due date (very fast)
        set completed of every reminder in list myList whose completed is false and name is myTitle to true
    end try
end tell
```

And here's a screen recording showing that it runs in about 13s (compared to the other solution, which takes between 1m30s and 2m30s).

https://drive.google.com/open?id=187J4PV0qM9fB8ycdVoZBqjtBqAmYDBh2&authuser=hepcat72%40gmail.com&usp=drive_fs

Note, if there's a timeout error on the slow portion of the code, the error string is returned.

Comment: The code could probably be cleaned up a bit, and I haven't tested the slow case yet, but the fast case works.

Comment: I have found a wrinkle with this. The due date returned for recurring reminders does not match the next due date shown in the reminders app when you use the 1-line statement. It works for non-recurring reminders. I just finished writing a perl script that retrieves reminders given search criteria including name, list, complete status, & whether it's past-due, future-due, has no due-date, or an `or`'d combo. I call it from a version of this applescript and it completes reminders with any due date value. It runs in a handful of seconds unless there's an actual future-due reminder to not complete

Comment: I will update my answer when I have time...

Comment: Did some more testing this morning. My perl script is spot-on and retrieves accurate info I can use to determine whether I can run the fast AppleScript code or slow, however if (in the Reminders app) you complete then uncomplete a recurring reminder, neither version works accurately. The 1-line version completes all occurrences shown in the Reminders app and the slow version completes none. But I believe this is an Apple bug because when I just return all matching reminders, the completed states disagree between the app and the returned properties. Will continue to test tomorrow...

Comment: All right! I have progress to report. It appears that whether it's 1 line or not, if there's a reminders synch issue (which I frequently see), the reminder the Reminders app is displaying is not the same one that the "every reminder" command returns. I learned how to take the reminder ID returned by my perl script & use it in my AppleScript to "complete" it. There's no AppleScript way to obtain that reminder. And if you try to modify the one the "every reminder" command returns, it throws an error. I will implement my solution to this problem tomorrow by using the IDs perl returns.

Comment: I wasn't seeing the modification reminder error because its values didn't match my search terms. It was "complete". So I returned properties of every reminder and found it. Thats how I encountered the error when trying to modify it... Anyway, more tomorrow...

Comment: OK. I have refined my script. It works around every common issue I encounter and runs very fast, relatively. The perl code is tweaked as well, though it relies on a module I haven't published yet, so I may take the time to create a package that wraps in a version of that module. I'll at least update my answer with the applescript code and some screen recordings next, probably tomorrow.